# How to generate Allure HTML report using playwright/test runner?

Tags: html, playwright, allure

How to generate Allure HTML report using playwright/test runner?

We are planning to use Nodejs, Typescript and Playwright recommended test runner (playwright/test) but wasn't able to find any documentation regarding how to generate Allure HTML report using the mentioned technology stack. There are other report formats like json and junit but we would like to generate Allure HTML report and like to attach screenshots and videos for failed test cases. Any references would be really helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Install

```sh
npm i -D @playwright/test allure-playwright
```

Run

```sh
npx playwright test --reporter=line,allure-playwright
allure generate ./allure-result --clean
allure open ./allure-report
```

or

```js
// playwright.config.ts
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  reporter: 'allure-playwright',
};
export default config;
```

You can specify target folder using `ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR` environment variable. e.g.

```
ALLURE_RESULTS_DIR=my-allure-results npx playwright test --reporter=line,allure-playwright
```

For more information, see here: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-js/blob/master/packages/allure-playwright/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Apart from allure, you can also generate elegant [Monocart](https://github.com/cenfun/monocart-reporter) report from [playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters#third-party-reporter-showcase):

Install:

```
npm i -D monocart-reporter
```

Run:

```
// playwright.config.js
module.exports = {
    reporter: [
        ['list'],
        ['monocart-reporter', {  
            name: "My Test Report",
            outputFile: './test-results/report.html'
        }]
    ]
};
```

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/cenfun/monocart-reporter